# Help me to create Drupal view to get similar result as from this sql query i provided (Organic group view0

Tags: views, organic-groups

```
SELECT B.title, c.name
FROM `og_membership` AS A
INNER JOIN `node` AS B ON A.gid = B.nid
INNER JOIN `users` AS C ON A.etid = C.uid
INNER JOIN `users_roles` AS D ON C.uid = D.uid
WHERE B.type = 'viu_course'
AND D.rid =7
```

here: B.type = viu_course is a content type and D.rid = 7 is the student role.

Please provide me, how to create view from view UI to get the similar result i get from this query.

Comment: Ok, I solved it myself. Thanks for giving space to ask.

Comment: Glad you did it. Why don't you post a self-answer? :) It should be possible already, or at least pretty soon (I'm not sure about current time limits).

Comment: Create View with Show OG Membership, Display format is table in my case.create Relationship 
1.Group Node from OG membership

2.Create User from OG membership (Do not use the relationship)

Now you can add field Content: Title (Relationship->Group node from OG membership)
user:Name (Relationship->user from og membership)

you can add the filter criteria as you required like (Use respective relationship)
Content:Type
User:Roles